# FFmpeg: How to encoding h264 mkv files in h265 mkv and keep the 2 subtitles streams?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, subtitles, cuda, x265

I've lots of mkv files in h264 format with 2 languages of subtitle, and I'm trying to convert them in h265 (with cuda) and keep the 2 subtitles streams.

I've tried that:

```
ffmpeg -i "xxx.mkv" -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -c:v hevc_nvenc -crf 26 -preset medium -rc vbr_hq -c:a aac -b:a 384k "xxx.mkv"
```

but I've an error:

> "Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmap"

And when I left the default settings without -map option, it burns the 1st subtitle stream directly on the video...

How can I do that?

Comment: Well, no answer here... But I found the solution on another website, and I post the solution if it can help somebody !

Answer (score 1):

Well, no answer here... But I found the solution on another website, and I post the solution if it can help somebody !

Here's the prompt: `ffmpeg -i "xxxx.mkv" -map 0 -c:v hevc_nvenc -crf 26 -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -c:a aac -b:a 384k -c:s copy "xxxx.mkv"`

With that, I keep all the subtitles streams and all the audio tracks! Cool!